# Почему мой PyQt5 код ничего не работает?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты

Я пишу программу, которая должна выводить ответ в зависимости от того, какой `radioButton` выбран:

**converter.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

criteries = {'В разработке': 'A1',
    'Утверждённые к разработке': 'A2',
    'Обоснованные к разработке': 'A3',
    'Разработка ожидается/задерживается': 'A4',
    'Разработка не выяснена/нецелесообразна': 'A5',}

class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(667, 336)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 141, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 30, 221, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 30, 151, 16))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 50, 3, 61))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 50, 3, 61))
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        self.line_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 50, 16, 61))
        self.line_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line_3.setProperty("color", QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        self.line_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_3.setObjectName("line_3")
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 120, 91, 16))
        self.radioButton.setChecked(False)
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.radioButton.text = 'В разработке'
        self.radioButton.toggled.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 150, 181, 21))
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        self.radioButton.text = 'Утверждённые к разработке'
        self.radioButton_2.toggled.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.radioButton_3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 180, 201, 21))
        self.radioButton_3.setObjectName("radioButton_3")
        self.radioButton.text = 'Обоснованные к разработке'
        self.radioButton_3.toggled.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.radioButton_4 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 120, 161, 31))
        self.radioButton_4.setObjectName("radioButton_4")
        self.radioButton.text = 'Разработка ожидается/задерживается'
        self.radioButton_4.toggled.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.radioButton_5 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 120, 171, 31))
        self.radioButton_5.setObjectName("radioButton_5")
        self.radioButton.text = 'Разработка не выяснена/нецелесообразна'
        self.radioButton_5.toggled.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.response = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.response.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 260, 221, 41))
        self.response.setText("")
        self.response.setObjectName("response")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "converter"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Промышленные проекты"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Потенцильно промышленные проекты"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Некоммерческие проектыl"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "В разработке"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Утверждённые к разработке"))
        self.radioButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Обоснованные для разработки"))
        self.radioButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Разработка ожидается/задерживается"))
        self.radioButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Разработка не выяснена/нецелесообразна"))  
    
    def onClicked(self):
        radioButton = self.sender()
        if radioButton.isChecked():
            self.response.setText(criteries.get(radioButton.text))
            print(criteries.get(radioButton.text))
        else:
            print("1")
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

В консоль при нажатии любой кнопки выводится **`1`** и `None`, за исключением первой, она даёт **`1`** и **`A5`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ** код, сгенерированный *Qt Designer*, **НИКОГДА**. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


criteries = {
    'В разработке': 'A1',
    'Утверждённые к разработке': 'A2',

#     vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    
#    'Обоснованные к разработке': 'A3',
    'Обоснованные для разработки': 'A3',
    
    'Разработка ожидается/задерживается': 'A4',
    'Разработка не выяснена/нецелесообразна': 'A5',
}

# ??? class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(667, 336)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 141, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 30, 221, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 30, 151, 16))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 50, 3, 61))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 50, 3, 61))
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        self.line_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 50, 16, 61))
        self.line_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line_3.setProperty("color", QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        self.line_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_3.setObjectName("line_3")
        
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 120, 91, 16))
        self.radioButton.setChecked(False)
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        
#        self.radioButton.text = 'В разработке'
#        self.radioButton.toggled.connect(self.onClicked)
        
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 150, 181, 21))
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")

#        self.radioButton.text = 'Утверждённые к разработке'
#        self.radioButton_2.toggled.connect(self.onClicked)

        self.radioButton_3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 180, 201, 21))
        self.radioButton_3.setObjectName("radioButton_3")
        
#        self.radioButton.text = 'Обоснованные к разработке'
#        self.radioButton_3.toggled.connect(self.onClicked)
        
        self.radioButton_4 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 120, 161, 31))
        self.radioButton_4.setObjectName("radioButton_4")
        
#        self.radioButton.text = 'Разработка ожидается/задерживается'
#        self.radioButton_4.toggled.connect(self.onClicked)
        
        self.radioButton_5 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 120, 171, 31))
        self.radioButton_5.setObjectName("radioButton_5")

#        self.radioButton.text = 'Разработка не выяснена/нецелесообразна'
#        self.radioButton_5.toggled.connect(self.onClicked)
        
        self.response = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.response.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 260, 221, 41))
        self.response.setText("")
        self.response.setObjectName("response")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "converter"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Промышленные проекты"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Потенцильно промышленные проекты"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Некоммерческие проектыl"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "В разработке"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Утверждённые к разработке"))

# ---------------------------------------------------------->vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.radioButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Обоснованные для разработки"))

        self.radioButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Разработка ожидается/задерживается"))
        self.radioButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Разработка не выяснена/нецелесообразна"))  

'''    
    def onClicked(self):
        radioButton = self.sender()
        if radioButton.isChecked():
            self.response.setText(criteries.get(radioButton.text))
            print(criteries.get(radioButton.text))
        else:
            print("1")
'''            

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)    
        
        self.radioButton.toggled.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.radioButton_2.toggled.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.radioButton_3.toggled.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.radioButton_4.toggled.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.radioButton_5.toggled.connect(self.onClicked)

    def onClicked(self):
        radioButton = self.sender()
        
        if radioButton.isChecked():
            print(f'\nOn radioButton: {radioButton.text()}')
        
#            self.response.setText(criteries.get(radioButton.text))
            self.response.setText(criteries[radioButton.text()])

#            print(criteries.get(radioButton.text))
        else:
            print(f"Off radioButton: {radioButton.text()}")        
            
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    
#    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
#    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]